# How does Asymptote populate type triple when it is assigned an algebraic expression with 3d shapes?

Tags: miktex, asymptote

The 3d Asymptote code below declares `triple circleCenter = (Y+Z)/sqrt(2) + X;`.

The Asymptote docs define type triple as

> "An ordered triple of real components (x,y,z) used for three-dimensional
> drawings. The respective components of a triple v can read as v.x, v.y, and
> v.z. The implicit initializer for triples is (0.0,0.0,0.0)."

In this case does Asymptote populate each individual component (x,y,z) with the value of (1+1)/sqrt(2) + 1?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`X = (1, 0, 0)`, `Y = (0, 1, 0)`, `Z = (0, 0, 1)`, and the operations are performed component-wise: `((0+0)/sqrt(2)+1, (1+0)/sqrt(2)+0, (0+1)/sqrt(2)+0)`. This is similar to operations on vectors in mathematics.